# Stop running the remainder of this Javascript code, if the URL contains given text

Tags: javascript

I'm using Greasekit on Fluid app, and I wish to deactivate a script it the currently loaded URL contains `chutney`.

[In FluidApp]: **Window ---> Userscripts ---> Patterns**

I wish that I could do it by setting the patterns: I have added `*amazon.co.uk*` so the script is only active on the Amazon UK site. (this works fine and dandy)
However, in addition, the URL is contains `chutney` (for example `https://www.amazon.co.uk/private/forum?ie=UTF8&tab=chutney`) I want it to turn off (ignore) the script.
Is there a boolean type expression that means the **opposite** of `*chutney*`? (if there is, that would solve the problem!)

## Plan B

If not, is perhaps I should try and modify the actual script, so that it only runs on the condition that `chutney` is not in the URL bar of the page. (Can I do this in code?)

Comment: Isn't there a "disallow" drop down in the "allow" UI?

Comment: @AlexK sadly, no, all i see is this: http://i.imgur.com/CZykSbq.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can help you with Plan A that much, but Plan B is simply wrapping all the code in an if statement with the condition `location.href.indexOf("chutney")==-1`.

If you want to use Plan A: Finding the rules for the creating of patterns (`*` counts as any number of characters, etc.) will help.